# Does anyone know the connection code to log into SAP GUI automated through VBA?

Tags: vba, windows-10, sap-gui

I am having trouble with Windows 10 and my connection code in VBA to automatically open SAP Logon, login for me, and begin the macro. Is there a standard piece of code for Windows 10?

I have the code for the older version of Windows, but I keep getting a run time error because it doesn't exactly know what/where the new version of SAP GUI that is installed.

I am getting an error on this line (full code below) when it starts looking for the system that we use:

```
Set Connection = SAP_Applic.OpenConnection("XXXX", True) 'Enter your system here.
```

The system name is correctly within the quotations so I have no idea where the error is in that line or why it's not even opening SAP GUI.

```
If Sheets("Start").Range("E9") = "Yes" Then
    On Error Resume Next
        Set SapGuiAuto = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If SapGuiAuto Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "Please start SAPlogon"
             Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        Set SAP_Applic = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        On Error GoTo 0
        If SAP_Applic Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "Scripting disabled"
             Exit Sub
        End If
        Set Connection = SAP_Applic.OpenConnection("", True)   'Enter your system here
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
     If IsObject(WScript) Then
        WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
        WScript.ConnectObject SAP_Applic, "on"
     End If
```

Comment: I'm *guessing* the error you're getting is "ActiveX can't create object" at `Set SapGuiAuto = CreateObject(...)`?

Comment: Does the ProgID "Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl" exist in the Windows registry? Try removing the `.1`.

Comment: Mathieu... When I remove the .1 it becomes nothing an it gives me the error msgbox that I created right underneath it.

Comment: Ok, so `CreateObject` is working. *What error are you getting, and where*?

Comment: I am getting an error on this line when it starts looking for the system that we use.. The system name is correctly within the quotations so I have no idea where the error is in that line or why its not even opening SAP.                                                                                                                 Set Connection = SAP_Applic.OpenConnection("", True)   'Enter your system here

Comment: Ok, so this has nothing to do with Win10, as far as COM and typelib registrations are concerned, everything is fine. Maybe that empty string needs to contain a connection string or something? Refer to SAP API documentation. The comment does say "enter your system here", so ...have you tried "entering your system here" instead of that empty string?